# I cannot find the man page for malloc on my Ubuntu WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, manpage

So far I have tried `man malloc` and `man 3 malloc`

additionally, I have updated my system with `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt install man-db` and `sudo apt install manpages-posix`

I can search man pages for other functions just fine.

Comment: try `apt install build-essential`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Rob I think that you know that I vote-to-close a lot of off-topic questions here, but I'm thinking this one is on-topic as it is *specifically* about the manpage for a Linux library function.  I also didn't see any duplicates.  Thoughts?

Comment: @J-JacquesM I know it's simple and straightforward, but please make that an answer rather than a comment - But take the word "try" out of it, because sometimes people think that means it's "not an answer".  Thanks!